# Firebase Storage security rules. Read access for authenticated users NOT working

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I would like to allow read access for only authenticated users.
The rules I configured are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected in the simulator:
[image]

But rarelly, the behaivour of the real App the images are not showed in the ListView, and returns this error in the "GET image":
[image]

Did anyone had the same problem? Any way to fix?

Comment: The URL in that second screenshot looks like a download URL (as first glance, it's hard to be certain from just the partial screenshot). Download URLs provide public read-only access and are not checked against your security rules, so the error won't be coming from there. You might want to check the body of he response.